# How can I tell Linux to keep a page and not evict it?

Tags: linux, paging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I tell Linux not to swap out a particular processes' memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/578137/can-i-tell-linux-not-to-swap-out-a-particular-processes-memory)

I want to allocate a chunk of memory in **Linux** and be sure that it will get no #GP or #PF faults. Regarding #GP, it's my responsibility as a programmer to ensure that I do not exceed any bounds. However, #PF are the the responsibility of the OS, since it can choose whether or not to evict a page.

I imagine that if I use the same page frequently, the OS will be smart enough not to evict it. However, if I want to allocate a large block of memory, then it'll take me a while to reach some of the pages, and I don't want the OS to evict it in the meanwhile.

Is there any way to tell **Linux** to keep a page present so that I never get a page fault?

Note: This is similar to to the question [*How can I tell **Windows** to keep a page and not evict it?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7242148/how-can-i-tell-windows-to-keep-a-page-and-not-evict-it) except that this one is about Linux

Comment: @Steve: you're right.  I'm voting to close.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`mlock`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/mlock.2.html).

Comment: remember, the total number of `mlock`-ed pages is limited by `ulimit -l`.